# API For Additional Storage Details Softlayer

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For a given virtual guest, how should i get the attached additional storage details using api. Information like storage name, storage ID etc for softlayer only.
Please provide the api if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an objectMask to retrieve additional information related to the object you are using.
The next are some examples that might help you:

Method: GET

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$virtualGuestId/getObject?objectMask=mask[datacenter,blockDevices[diskImage[capacity,type[name],units]],networkStorage,allowedHost,allowedNetworkStorage[serviceResource[networkDevice[datacenter]],serviceResourceBackendIpAddress,storageType],allowedNetworkStorageReplicas,evaultNetworkStorage[serviceResource[networkDevice[datacenter]]]]
```

Method: POST

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$virtualGuestId/getAttachedNetworkStorages?objectMask=mask[id,username,capacityGb,nasType,notes,serviceResource[id,networkDevice[id,datacenter],type],storageType,storageTierLevel,replicationPartners[id,username,capacityGb,nasType,notes,serviceResource[id,networkDevice[id,datacenter],type],storageType,storageTierLevel,serviceResourceBackendIpAddress],serviceResourceBackendIpAddress]

Payload:
{
    "parameters": ["*"]
}
```

Regarding to the Portable storages the only way to distinguish them is by calling the method SoftLayer_Account::getPortableStorageVolumes and apply a filter to the Virtual Guest id.

e.g.

Method: GET

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPortableStorageVolumes?objectFilter={"portableStorageVolumes":{"blockDevices":{"guest":{"id":{"operation":$virtualGuestId}}}}}
```

Note: Replace $username, $apiKey and $virtualGuestId with your information.

Additional information about object-masks can be found in the next link:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

There’s also valuable information about Storage services in the next link:
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/